# Why can´t i use the properties of a button using a variable in place of the button name?

Tags: variables, tkinter, button, properties

```
btarray = np.full((3, 3), "red", dtype="object")
arfinal = []
btpressed = ""

def clickbutton(arvalue, btpressed):
    print (arvalue)
    print (btpressed)
    a,b=arvalue.split(',')
    a,b=int(a),int(b)
    if btarray[a,b] == "red":
        btarray[a,b] = "green"
        btpressed.configure(bg=(btarray[a,b]))
    else:
        btarray[a,b] = "red"
        btpressed.configure(bg=(btarray[a,b]))
    print(btarray)

btn = Button(window, bg=btarray[0, 0], activebackground="blue", height=5, width=10, command= lambda: clickbutton("0, 0", "btn"))
```

---

So it gives me the error:

```
 btpressed.configure(bg=(btarray[a,b]))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'configure'
```

---

But changing the type of the variable btpressed to object doesn´t seem to help. If i write in the name of the button directly, like btn it works fine, but there are a bunch of buttons and i don´t want a function for each of them, just one that works for all, thanks.

Comment: Change `command= lambda: clickbutton("0, 0", "btn")` to `command=lambda: clickbutton("0, 0", btn)`

Comment: omg that was it, that´s me being stupid making it a string. You are absolutely right, thank you so much, works perfect now

Comment: btw if you re-use the `btn` variable name (after the `btn = Button(...)` that's in your code), my approach isn't going to work. Just putting it out there for anyone that looks at this in the future

Answer (score 0):

Change command= lambda: clickbutton("0, 0", "btn") to command=lambda: clickbutton("0, 0", btn) – TheLizzard 12 mins ago